Implementing a trait where the order of generics matter?
I have types Product<A, B> and Ratio<A, B> where A: BaseUnit, B: BaseUnit. I'm struggling to figure out how I can implement traits where the order of the generics matter.
My first implementation is for A/BC * B -> A/C:
impl<A: BaseUnit, B: BaseUnit, C: BaseUnit> std::ops::Mul<B>
    for Ratio<A, Product<B, C>>
{
    type Output = Ratio<A, C>;
    fn mul(self, rhs: B) -> Self::Output {
        (self.value() * rhs.value()).into()
    }
}

then I want to implement A/BC * C -> A/B. However this implementation conflicts with the previous one:
impl<A: BaseUnit, B: BaseUnit, C: BaseUnit> std::ops::Mul<C>
    for Ratio<A, Product<B, C>>
{
    type Output = Ratio<A, B>;
    fn mul(self, rhs: C) -> Self::Output {
        (self.value() * rhs.value()).into()
    }
}

as I understand it this is because B and C when used as the generic for std::ops::Mul<T> are indistinguishable to the compiler, and perhaps it's the same with Ratio<A, C> vs Ratio<A, B>. Is there any way around this?

The problem is that there is no way to tell the compiler that B and C are different types. So if you have a Ratio<A, Product<B, B>> which implementation should the compiler use? (Note that the compiler never looks inside the implementations, and so has no way to realize that they are identical in that situation).

here B and C have the same constraints, so the compiler has the right to assume they can be the same type, meaning you are implementing the same trait twice with a different associated types, this is not allowed by the compiler.

I suppose the compiler gives you an error:
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `Mul<_>` for type `Ratio<_, Product<_, _>>`

From the compiler's perspective, you implemented the Mul twice for the same Ratio<A, Product<B, C>>.
Alternatively, you could use a single templated implementation impl Mul for Ratio, but make it work at the place of usage. Essentially, your formula looks as follows:

A/T1T2 * T1 -> A/T2

Let's apply to both your cases:

A/BC * B -> A/C
A/CB * C -> A/B (instead of A/BC * C...)

Playground (working example): https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=39315f168b9b3a861585fb33f48cd948
You can see how it works at the bottom:
    // A/BC * B -> A/C
    let ratio_ac = ratio_abc * RealB;
    
    // A/CB * C -> A/B
    let ratio_ab = ratio_acb * RealC;


Thanks. This does compile but unfortunately isn't as ergonomic as I'd like; as I understand it this means if I have Product<B, C> and I want to do A/BC * C -> A/B then it requires me to turn Product<B, C> into Product<C, B>. I was hoping that both A/BC * C and A/BC * B would work without needing to think about the order of the generics.
What I ended up doing was just using a macro to manually implement std::ops::Mul for the concrete types, e.g. Product<Watts, Hours> * Watts and Product<Watts, Hours> * Hours, etc. Not ideal but it works!

Yes, changing your approach is probably the best answer. Basically, Product<B, C> == Product<C, B>, it is the same for the compiler at the point of generics definition (e.g. Product<T1, T2>). It defines some template, placeholder. The difference arises when you put concrete types in place of type usage: Product<ConcreteA, ConcreteB> != Product<ConcreteB, ConcreteA>: you just need one template for both implementations.
